# What is the difference between encrypting and signing in ECC asymmetric algorithm?

Tags: encryption, public-key, elliptic-curves, dsa

What is the difference between encrypting some data vs signing some data (using ECC)?

Does it simply reverse the role of the public-private keys?

In the past, I thought it was just a change of role for publickey and privatekey.

As the diagram:
[image: Encrypt diagram]
(Encrypt diagram)
[image]
(Sign diagram)

But in practice, it seem not easy like me think.

For example, I can't use ECDSA public key to encrypt and private key corresponding to decrypt.

In this case I must use ECDH.

I do not have much experience on this issue. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECDSA is just for signing. It stands for Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm. EdDSA is another signing algorithm, with some added security. ECDH is for key exchange: it creates a new secret key shared by both parties which no passive eavesdropper can discover.

ECC is pretty much never used to directly encrypt a message. Instead ECDH is used to create a shared secret key, and then a secret-key (symmetric) algorithm such as AES-GCM or ChaCha20+Poly1305 is used to transmit the secret data. The same thing is typically done with RSA, since asymmetric cryptography is slow it's faster to create a shared secret key and use symmetric cryptography. ECIES is a standard that does this, and several variants of the "ECDH+Symmetric encryption" idea are included in TLS.

The main use of direct encryption using an asymmetric algorithm would be a PGP-like system for encrypting e-mail or other old asynchronous protocols where no prior key agreement step is possible. I am not aware of any standard that uses ECC to do this.

Comment: "ECDSA is just for signing. It stands for Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm. EdDSA is another signing algorithm, with some added security." ----> can you show me this?

Comment: https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ has the specifications of EdDSA, in the papers section.